# How can one specify dpi when saving image as tif via scipy.misc.imsave?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, ocr, tesseract

I am taking a screen-shot (PNG format) resizing it, and writing it back out in TIF format, via `scipy.misc` module (imread, imresize, imsave functions). The TIF format image is to be fed into Tesseract-OCR. However, Tesseract is complaining that the *dpi specified in the TIF file's metadata is 0*. How can one specify this when saving the image via `scipy.misc.imsave` or any other method?

Answer (score 3):

Without analyzing where your problems exactly come from, [the approach of Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46650207/2320035) (maybe that's enough for you; maybe not; i can imagine there is something else in your code which might be the reason) can be emulated by using [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) (and i don't see an option for this within scipy's wrapper).

Actually, instead of rewriting tags as he does, we care about these while doing our original task. In practice both approaches should be okay.

With a very high probability, scipy is already [using Pillow under the hood](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html) (`Note that Pillow (https://python-pillow.org/) is not a dependency of SciPy, but the image manipulation functions indicated in the list below are not available without it.`; this list contains `imsave`).

```
from scipy.misc import ascent    # test image
import PIL.Image

scipy_img = ascent().astype('uint8')
arr2im = PIL.Image.fromarray(scipy_img)

arr2im.save('test.tif', format='TIFF',
        dpi=(100., 100.),  # there still seems to be a bug when using int's here
        compression='tiff_lzw',)
```

Checking with exiftool:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.63
File Name                       : test.tif
...
Image Width                     : 512
Image Height                    : 512
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Compression                     : LZW
...
X Resolution                    : 100
Y Resolution                    : 100
...
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Image Size                      : 512x512
Megapixels                      : 0.262
```

Answer (score 1):

Please file this one under *"any other method"* :-)

You can set the resolution with `exiftool` like this:

```
exiftool SomeImage.tif  -xresolution=300 -yresolution=300 -resolutionunit=inches
```

Check it with **ImageMagick**:

```
identify -verbose SomeImage.tif

Image: SomeImage.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 100x100+0+0
  Resolution: 300x300
  Print size: 0.333333x0.333333
  ...
  ...
```

I am suggesting you shell out to run this command with `os.system()`.

A [Python wrapper](https://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) exists, but I have never used it and cannot vouch for it.